# Calculating length of road network within a polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, intersection, area, road

I have a road network stored in a gdb and some polygons in another gdb.

I want to populate an attribute for each polygon with the total length (in km) of the road network that it overlaps.

Any idea on how to do that?